# Factor 2 in even integrand (distribution) on an even interval

Tags: integration, distribution-theory

When I have an even function $f(x)=f(-x)$ we can write

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) = 2 \int^{\infty}_0 f(x)$$
Now if we allow $f(x)$ to be a distribution, specifically to contain delta functions, the above result no longer seems to hold.

It overcounts the contribution at 0. This normally doesn't matter for a function since it has measure zero but if $f(x)$ contains Dirac Delta function at $x=0$ the result is now different. So when I use this trick I guess I have to be careful with end points where $f(x)$ is not a function.

---

Should I split the integral into $\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}f(x) + \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}f(x) + \int_{\epsilon}^\infty f(x)$. Then the first and last term will be equal by evenness of $f(x)$.

Does this subtlety only arise when integrating over a distribution that is not a function at the point of symmetry (and thus at the end-point when we try to split the integral)?

Comment: I will start with measures first: If you have a (finite) signed measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $\mu(A)=\mu(-A)$ for all measurable $A\subset\mathbb R$, then: $$\mu(\mathbb R)=\mu(]-\infty, 0[)+\mu(\{0\})+\mu(]0,\infty[)=\mu(\{0\})+2\mu(]0,\infty[).$$ If $\mu$ has an $L^1$-density $f$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure this reduces to $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) = 2 \int^{\infty}_0 f(x).$$

Comment: When you take a distribution more subtleties arise with the topology: For example, do you mean by a distribution an operator in $C_b(\mathbb R)^*$ with the topology induced by the $L^\infty$-norm ?

Comment: Haha, physicist here. I should not have used terminology I don't fully understand. I was only thinking "functions" $f(x)$ containing delta functions. Not any other non-function behaviour. (I'm having a hard time fully understanding your comments.)

Comment: I think I know what you mean: If you have "no Dirac functional at $0$" then you can safely use the $\int_{-\infty}^\infty=2\int_0^\infty$-formula. More formally, if $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure and you have a measure of the form $$\mu=\delta_{x_1}+\dots+\delta_{x_n}+ f\lambda,$$ where $f\in L^1$ and $x_1,\dots,x_n\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, then we have $$\int_{\mathbb R} \,\mathrm d\mu = 2\int_{[0,\infty[}\,\mathrm d\mu.$$